# How to search value in multidimensional array by all key and get key - value of matched data php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 287
            [fname] => Vivek
            [sname] => Makwana
            [serial] => 72
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 288
            [fname] => Vishal
            [sname] => Makwana
            [serial] => 87
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 289
            [fname] => Nilesh
            [sname] => Desai
            [serial] => 98
        )
)
```

I want to get ID of serached data in array, like if I search 'vi' then array matches 2 values in key fname, values 'Vivek' and 'Vishal'.

So I want only key [ID] of matched data 287 and 288.

How can I get this ID of matched values?

Comment: To improve your specification, are we supposed to write you code to include a search of the `fname` and `sname` fields of just the `fname`

Comment: I want all fields to search ID, fname, sname, serial

Comment: You are going to need a `foreach` loop and then you could look up `strpos()` in the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried many things array_search, in_array, array_filter and also searched in google, stack overflow I have find that answers of searched by perticular key like only fname but I needed to search by all keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are trying to find a magic builtin function, there are none.

Simply loop over the array and test the fields you are interested in to see if the value you are interested in is in there. I use `stripos()` so it will ignore case, so it will match `vi` or `Vi` or `VI` or even `vI`

```
$array = [  ['ID' => 287, 'fname' => 'Vivek', 'sname' => 'Makwana', 'serial' => 72],
            ['ID' => 288, 'fname' => 'Vishal', 'sname' => 'Makwana', 'serial' => 73],
            ['ID' => 289, 'fname' => 'Nilesh', 'sname' => 'Nilesh', 'serial' => 75]
        ];


function search($array, $for) 
{
    $results = [];

    foreach ( $array as $arr) {
        $a = stripos($arr['fname'], $for);
        $b = stripos($arr['sname'], $for);
        if ( $a !== FALSE || $b !== FALSE ) {
             // save the id
             $results[] = $arr['ID']; 
        }
    }
    return $results;
}


print_r(search($array, 'vi'));
```

RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [0] => 287
    [1] => 288
)
```